# Django FTP server 550 Not enough privileges error

Tags: python, django, ftp, django-ftpserver

I'm using [Django FTP server](https://django-ftpserver.readthedocs.org/), it uses user authentication of Django.

I'm able to log with the ascoounts created with FileZilla

But the I'm not able to list the directory conte or upload, Getting the following error

```
Status: Connecting to 10.3.0.139:10021...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 pyftpdlib 1.4.0 ready.
Command:    USER LdDXorZEgytTevVIfbYmegwWlVeTPP
Response:   331 Username ok, send password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 welcome.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   501 Invalid argument.
Command:    OPTS MLST type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
Response:   200 MLST OPTS type;perm;size;modify;unix.mode;unix.uid;unix.gid;
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (10,3,0,139,137,129).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   550 Not enough privileges.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Any Idea? I've set `777` permission for the user home directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP User need to be added to any of the FTP User Group and the group need to have `elradfmw` permission.

You can set it from Django FTP group section of Django admin panel.